# iOS background service using BLE after reboot

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm new to mobile development, before eventually deciding where to develop (android/ iOS) a specific application I have a question (I'd prefer using an iPhone):

So the background is that I have a BLE device frequently sending data to the phone and let the phone app sync the data to the cloud. Now, it is really important that if for some reason the phone has to restart, it will automatically proceed receiving the BLE data.

Is it possible at all in iOS to start a background process (handling BLE packets) after reboot automatically. Thus e.g. when the respective BLE device pairs to the phone after a reboot, that the background process starts automatically, without the user having to start the app manually?

Doing some research I came up with mixed results regarding this scenario and would be grateful if someone with iOS experience could clarify.

(BTW: It does not have to be an Apple App Store Application)

Answer (score 0):

A Few days ago I was working on BLE devices Beacons we supposed to make mobile application and start monitoring these beacons and send date monitoring to API.

This works fine in background, even the user was not running the application in foreground or reboot his iPhone.

All we should do is put the monitoring code at the appDelegate of the application to work in the background.